how to query a Snowflake Network Rule value list
Im fetching data from an api where i have hard encoded the url while its defined in a netwrok rule
is there a way to  get the api url from the network rule dynamically to pass it to my SP in snowflake  ?
select statement doesn't work
no meta data table from snowflake that stores network rule values  where you can query it as a table

Sadly, no (unless there is something new I'm not aware of).
All you have is SHOW PARAMETERS LIKE 'network_policy' IN USER "the_user" for every user, which is a pain if you're trying to build a nice governance solution.

You can store all the rules in a table by using RESULT_SCAN
SHOW NETWORK RULES;

INSERT INTO temp_network_rules
SELECT "name", "entries_in_valuelist"
FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));


you can query snowflake.account_usage.network_rules snowflake account_usage views. You should be able to access the view using the ACCOUNTADMIN Role or SECURITY_VIEWER Snowflake database role.
select * from snowflake.account_usage.network_rules
where deleted is null
;```

Please keep in mind that for any new network rule changes, you have to wait up to 2 hours to reflect.

